# Firmware ath10k_pci Causes Errors

Tags: debian, wifi, drivers, dmesg, journalctl

A few months ago I started using Debian SID. Whenever I start my system I see with `journalctl -p 3 -xb`:

```
pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: Error of this Agent is reported first
ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: firmware: failed to load ath10k/pre-cal-pci-0000:02:00.0.bin (-2)
ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: firmware: failed to load ath10k/cal-pci-0000:02:00.0.bin (-2)
DMAR: DRHD: handling fault status reg 2
DMAR: [DMA Write NO_PASID] Request device [02:00.0] fault addr 0xfefe8000 [fault reason 0x05] PTE Write access is not set
```

At first this never bothered me or seemed to cause me any problems in daily use, however, recently I have been having problems with my wifi which keeps disconnecting and reconnecting by itself several times and when I tried to diagnose it I found in `dmesg -w`:

```
ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to flush transmit queue (skip 0 ar-state 1): 0
wlp2s0: Connection to AP 00:00:00:00:00:00 lost
wlp2s0: authenticate with <macaddress>
wlp2s0: 80 MHz not supported, disabling VHT
wlp2s0: send auth to <macaddress> (try 1/3)
wlp2s0: authenticated
wlp2s0: associate with <macaddress> (try 1/3)
wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from <macaddress> (capab=0x1411 status=30 aid=896)
wlp2s0: <macaddress> rejected association temporarily; comeback duration 1024 TU (1048 ms)
wlp2s0: associate with <macaddress> (try 2/3)
wlp2s0: associate with <macaddress> (try 3/3)
wlp2s0: association with <macaddress> timed out
wlp2s0: authenticate with <macaddress>
wlp2s0: 80 MHz not supported, disabling VHT
wlp2s0: send auth to <macaddress> (try 1/3)
wlp2s0: authenticated
wlp2s0: associate with <macaddress> (try 1/3)
wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from <macaddress> (capab=0x1411 status=0 aid=3)
wlp2s0: associated
```

And with `journalctl -xfu NetworkManager`:

```
device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: completed -> disconnected
device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> authenticating
device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating
device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> disconnected
device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: associating -> disconnected
device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> authenticating
device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating
device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: associating -> associated
device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> 4way_handshake
device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: associated -> 4way_handshake
device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: 4way_handshake -> completed
device (wlp2s0): ip:dhcp4: restarting
dhcp4 (wlp2s0): canceled DHCP transaction
dhcp4 (wlp2s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
dhcp4 (wlp2s0): state changed no lease
dhcp4 (wlp2s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: 4way_handshake -> completed
dhcp4 (wlp2s0): state changed new lease, address=<localip>
```

Does anyone have a tip? Do the logs I collected with `journalctl -p 3 -xb` have anything to do with the logs regarding WiFi instability?

I'm really trying to understand what's going on here and I've read many forums but it's difficult to resolve.